# Lookup overwrites previous object of array

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in a collection with this structure:

```
{
    "_id": "5ef88d2e2451d510907677c8",
    "salary": 0,
    "isFree": true,
    "active":true,
    ...
    "services":[
      {
        "service": "5ef87d49899e9e0cacceb7b3",
        "percentage": 20
      }
    ]
}
```

And I'm using this following aggregation:

```
    let stylists = await Stylist.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                active: true
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "services",
                let: {
                    services: "$services"
                },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $and: [
                                    {$in: ["$_id","$$services.service"]},
                                    {$eq: ["$active", true]}
                                ]
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "services"
            }
        }
    ]);
```

It does populate `services` but the problem is that it overrides the whole object and I lose the `value` and `percentage` fields.

How can I solve this?

This is the current aggregation result:

```
{
    "_id": "5ef88d2e2451d510907677c8",
    "salary": 0,
    "isFree": true,
    "active": true,
    ...
    "services": [
        {
            "_id": "5ef87d49899e9e0cacceb7b3",
            "active": true,
            "name": "თმის დავარცხნა",
            "price": 20,
            "profession": 2,
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: I think, it's not the correct way but somewhat helps you. https://mongoplayground.net/p/bbsSc9DvhPd

Comment: thanks, but its really hard to use

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But even I've been trying to solve this issue since last 15 mins. But couldn't find any answer

Answer (score 1):

`$lookup` doesn't understand you're trying to populate fields so it just overwrite them.

I would argue the easiest way to do this is to first `$unwind` the `services` field, then populate them and finally restoring the original structure like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      active: true
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$services"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "services",
      let: {
        services: "$services"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$_id",
                    "$$services.service"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$active",
                    true
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "service"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$service",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      salary: {
        $first: "$salary"
      },
      isFree: {
        $first: "$isFree"
      },
      active: {
        $first: "$active"
      },
      services: {
        $push: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$services",
            "$service"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongodb Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_hSEug9VE7B)

- You can achieve the same behaviour without `$unwind`ing but unless you can guarantee the service array be sorted by `service` id I would recommend against it as you'll have to iterate over the services X the look-uped array to populate the fields. Making the process a lot more expensive.

Comment: it would work, but there is a few problems, all fields gotta be written manually, afterwards they should be unwinded and mergeObjects is limited for M0, M2, M5 Clusters if i am correct

Comment: https://hastebin.com/ubegodezap.bash, its farthest i got to, but it can not get other fields

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: this query can not keep the other fields, `isFree`, `active`, etc.

Comment: i meant my query

Comment: Just drop them from the group stage in my query? https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Aa5Jl7z3Qj

Comment: yes but then i need to use $first which pushes them to array so then i must unwind them by hand

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it without having to write every field by myself. here is the pipeline:

```
        {
            $match: {
                active: true
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$services"
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "services",
                let: {
                    services: "$services"
                },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $and: [
                                    {$eq: ["$_id","$$services.service"]},
                                    {$eq: ["$active", true]}
                                ]
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "services.service"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$services.service"
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                services: {
                    $push: "$services"
                },
                data: {
                    $first: "$$ROOT"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                'data.services': "$services"
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                services: 0
            }
        },
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: "$data"
            }
        }
```